# Can I use nodejs with socket.io without returning HTML files?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I was trying to create a node.js server using socket.io but the resources I got seems to be serving HTML files, this is my first time using nodejs server though, sorry. I am actually building an android app in android studio using html and angularjs and I want to deploy my nodejs server in heroku, this is my server code so far:

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', client => {
    console.log("Someone connected");
});
server.listen(3000);
```

and in client side, in my controller:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.0/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    var socketio = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
})
```

Your help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, a nodejs server can be just a socket.io server if you want.  You will have to have some server somewhere that serves your HTML files though.

Comment: Yes. See: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/. This is a stand-alone `socket.io` client that isn't dependent on HTML

Comment: @Daniel, thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See: socket.io/docs/client-api. This is a stand-alone socket.io client that isn't dependent on HTML